# In Google Drive, how do I search for files that I own and that I've shared?

Tags: google-drive

I can't seem to figure out how to find the files that I've shared with people. The Google Help page on the [topic](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375114&p=empty_search_ww) provides a few clues but the following query is not allowed:

```
owner:me to:*
```

but a specific target is valid:

```
owner:me to:foo@bar.com
```

Any clues?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. It is strange Google doesn't have this as a search option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no parameter to what is described. What you could do instead is make use of Google's logic system, primarily used in search queries.

`owner: me to:foo@gmail.com OR to:seadrus@gmail.com OR to:Dan@gmail.com ...`

...And continuing to do so with every person on your contacts list/who you've shared things with. No easy way to go about, as far as I know.

#### Explanation of Google logical operators

- `OR` is a search operator that can be used multiple times. It asks Google to search for either `a OR b`.
- `AND` is a search operator that can be used multiple times. It asks Google to search for both `a AND b` -- redundant as Google automatically does this with a search query like
  `Green Jeans`.

There are more that are, as far as I can tell, are only relevant in the search engine.